# nth-child formula for hover state - all elements except the first one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select all elements except the first one for a hover state. I'm doing this using `nth-child()` selector.

I'm following this guide: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

It gives a formula for selecting *all but the first 5* - the example they give is below:

```
li:nth-child(n+6) {
    color: green;   
}
```

I want to take this and apply it so that it selects all but the **first** element. My approach to do that is so:

```
li:nth-child(n+1) {
    color: green;   
}
```

Is this not correct?

I need to try to apply this to a hover state situation, where it only performs the `:hover` action all all but the first li. See the embed below:

```css
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  a {
    margin-right: 1.8rem;
      padding-bottom: 23px;
  }
  
  #login-signup li:nth-child(n+1):hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #292c2e;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="login-signup">
      <li> <a href="#">No Underline</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
```

How do you apply the formula for selecting anything but the first element with nth-child? Does `:hover` not work with nth-child? I can't find any sources that say otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:nth-child()` works with `:hover` just fine. `:hover` is not the problem here.

Look closely at the n+6 example. As you mentioned, that's for the first 5. However notice that the expression says 6, not 5.

So to match all but the first element, you need to start from 2. Hence, n+2.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  margin-right: 1.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}

#login-signup li:nth-child(n+2):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #292c2e;
}
```

```html
<ul id="login-signup">
  <li><a href="#">No Underline</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `li:not(:first-child)` ?

Comment: That solves that issue, now I'm having a completely new issue in my project where that is causing two lines on hover...I may or may not post another SO question

Answer (score 4):

Personally I prefer to do this without nth child, and just use a simple sibling selector:

```css
li + li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `:not(:first-child)` to solve this, so you don't have to care about the formula:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
} 
a {
  margin-right: 1.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}
#login-signup li:not(:first-child):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #292c2e;
}
```

```html
<ul id="login-signup">
  <li> <a href="#">No Underline</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another solution using the `:not`:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
} 
a {
  margin-right: 1.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}
#login-signup li:not(:nth-child(1)):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #292c2e;
}
```

```html
<ul id="login-signup">
  <li> <a href="#">No Underline</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
} 
a {
  margin-right: 1.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}
#login-signup li:not(:eq(0)):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #292c2e;
}
```

```html
<ul id="login-signup">
  <li> <a href="#">No Underline</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
```